# Números primos en Erlang y la expresion Case

Tags: lista, recursión, números-primos, erlang

estoy aprendiendo Erlang y necesito hacer una función que retorne la lista de los números primos entre L y O. Por ejemplo, si L = 10 y O = 20, tiene que retornar 11, 13, 17 y 19. El código es el siguiente, pero solo me retorna el primer número primo.

```
primes(L,O) ->
    case L =< O of
        true ->
            case prime(L) of
                true ->
                    primes (L+1, O),
                    L;
                false ->
                    primes(L+1,O)
            end;
        false ->
            false
        end.
```

Cómo hago para hacer bien la recursión  y que me devuelva todos los primos?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la **solución**, basta con añadir una función con tres variables i que una de ellas sea la lista.

```
    primes(B, A) ->
    primes2(B, A, []). % Creem una funció que ja té inicialitzada una llista.

primes2(B, A, R)->
    case B =< A of
        true ->
            case prime(B) of
                true ->
                    primes2(B + 1, A, R++[B]);
                false ->
                    primes2(B + 1, A, R)
            end;
        false ->
            R
    end.
```

Answer (score 0):

En caso que necesites otra solución sin usar una lista para almacenar los valores aqui te dejo algo que podría ser de utilidad. Tu implementación estaba bastante bien, el problema era cómo tratabas de imprimir los primos.

```
primes(L,O) -> 
case L =< O of
    true ->
        case prime(L) of
            true ->
                io:format('~B~n',[L]), % esta es la forma en la que debes imprimir
                primes(L+1,O);
            false ->
                primes(L+1,O)
        end;
    false ->
        io:format('FIN~n',[])
end.
```

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias :)